# Inject Configuration into multiple Jenkins jobs via DSL

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

I have a number of maven project in Jenkins and I would like a mechanism where i can inject a piece of configuration into all of them at once.

or example if I decide to change the logRotation.

I found this can be done via the DSL plugin, but I so far I am only able to inject one project at a time.

```
mavenJob('EXAMPLE_TEST1') {
    publishers {
         textFinder(/There are test failures/, '', false, false, true)
   }
}
```

The above works and inject a piece of config for the textFinder plugin into a maven project

How do i achieve the same for EXAMPLE_TEST2, 3, 4, 5, 6 etc

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 1):

I decided to go a little further and create an array of all jobs in Jenkins

```
import hudson.model.*

allTests(Hudson.instance.items)


def allTests(items){
def list = []

for (item in items) {
  def name = item.getName()

  if (name.contains("API")){
  } else {
    list << item.getName()
 }
}

list.each { job ->  

mavenJob("${job}")
{
publishers {
    textFinder(/There are test failures/, '', false, false, true)
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Sorry for the above format

So this will now grab every job in Jenkins that does not contain the text API and add it to an array and will inject the configuration required.

Comment: Hmmm, a self-answered question should probably only have one self-answer.  You can edit your original answer to add this extra information, and then delete this extra answer.  Please.

Comment: Apologies, Done Jonathan

Comment: I don't think doing this is the right way (correct me if im wrong please!) because jenkins isn't tracking those jobs. this is somewhat related to my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51144018/loop-over-array-of-jobs-to-create-them. I'm trying to do what your doing but I want jenkins to delete renamed/unreferenced jobs and looping like this seems to not work. Or maybe I'm just missing something?